# Changing main form button visibility from the subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been trying to make a button disappear when a new insert is made and one of the fields is empty, problem is the field is on a subform (data sheet view) and the button on the main form I've been trying the following code with no success.

```
If Me.Produto = "" Then
        [Orçamentos]!Comando33.Visible = False
        [Orçamentos]!Comando47.Visible = False
        Me.Descrição.Visible = False
 End If
```

Any advice?

Comment: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Me` is the sub form, and `Orçamentos` is the main form:

```
If Me.Produto = "" Then
    Me.Parent!Comando33.Visible = False
    Me.Parent!Comando47.Visible = False
    Me.Descrição.Visible = False
End If
```